# Downstream Task In Reinforcement Learning

Tags: reinforcement-learning, self-supervised-learning

I have read some paragraph on Self supervision based reinforcement learning which just enables agent to learn without human supervision and effective strategy for unlabeled dataset training. But I found the "Downstream task" many times.
Now, What does it mean by "Downstream task" in Reinforcement Learning?

Answer (score 1):

A downstream task is a task which will be defined via task-specific rewards. This is usually done after doing unsupervised RL pretraining for a long time.

Self-supervision is usually necessary for this pre-training.